# How to execute " ls " command in the chroot?

Tags: ls, chroot

I have browser shell [leash](https://github.com/jcubic/leash) and I'm executing shell commands in php and returing them to the browser and I just discovered chroot command and I want to run for example `ls` on root directory on changed root, In fact I need to run `bash -c "ls /"`. I've try this (I've try without sudo but it was not working):

```
sudo chroot ~/projects/jcubic/leash ls
```

but got error:

```
chroot: failed to run command ‘ls’: No such file or directory
```

do I use this command properly? Is it possible to run ls on different root directory?

when I've try to run chroot without sudo I've got this error:

```
chroot: cannot change root directory to '/home/kuba/projects/jcubic/leash': Operation not permitted
```

Comment: Do you understand what `chroot` is supposed to do?

Comment: @SatoKatsura If I understand correctly I change `/` directory to different one. Do I need to have `bin` in that directory to run commands?

Comment: Yes: you need to populate the `chroot` jail beforehand with all binaries you want to run, all libraries they need, __and__ the dynamic loader (if your OS uses one).  Also only root can run `chroot`, as you found out.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
chroot: failed to run command ‘ls’: No such file or directory
```

To run any command inside the chroot, you need to have this program available in the chroot (since it can not use the program installed in the `/` of filesystem.

The simplest way is to copy the `/usr/bin/ls` from to `/home/kuba/projects/jcubic/leash/usr/bin/` (you will also need the dependent shared libraries: `ldd /usr/bin/ls`).

Comment: I've found this [article](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BasicChroot) on help.ubuntu.com, how should I run chroot, because I can't find that information. Should I run `chroot lucid /bin/bash -c "ls /"` or `chroot /var/chroot /bin/bash -c "ls /"`

Comment: @jcubic it very depends what you want to achieve. The manual page for `chroot` is a good place to start when you are in doubts about the syntax. The same thing for other commands (`bash`).

Answer (score 6):

It's possible to run `ls` in a different root, but the `ls` command and all the files it depends on must be present inside that root. There's no way to start the `ls` command, and then inside that process change the root: `ls` doesn't have this feature.

The whole point of a chroot is to limit the visibility of files to those under a certain directory. When you run `chroot ~/projects/jcubic/leash ls`, the `chroot` command changes the root of its own process (changing the root directory only affects the process that does it and any process that it subsequently runs), then attempts to run an executable file called `ls` in a directory on the search path. Since the root is now `~/projects/jcubic/leash`, the executable must be present in a directory such as `~/projects/jcubic/leash/bin`.

If you want to have a normal system with the usual commands in the chroot, you need to install one. Tools such as [debootstrap](https://wiki.debian.org/Debootstrap) (to install a Debian system) or provisioning tools such as Docker (which sets up an environment that's chrooted and is confined in other ways) can help.

If you just want the `ls` command, you'll still need to copy more than `ls`. To run `ls`, you'll need to copy the `ls` command as well as all the files it depends on. Since `ls` is a dynamically linked program, you need its dynamic loader as well as all the dynamic libraries it depends on. Run `ldd /bin/ls` to list the required dynamic libraries. For example:

```
mkdir -p bin lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
rsync -a /bin/ls bin/
rsync -a /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
chroot . ls
```

Alternatively, a simpler way to explore is to get a statically-linked binary, for example of [BusyBox](https://busybox.net/downloads/BusyBox.html) (available on Debian and derivatives as the `busybox-static` package).

```
cp /bin/busybox .
chroot . ./busybox ls
```